# thread fs segment register switching between user and kernel land

Tags: windows, multithreading, kernel

How does the fs segment register point to the TEB and KPCR. Are these data structures saved on the threads user and kernel stack? So is it a case of when a thread context switch takes place from user to kernel, the fs segment reg containing a pointer the TEB is saved onto the threads user stack and then the kernel fs segment register which points to the KPCR is loaded back into fs segment register? Is this how the fs segment register points to both TEB and KPCR?

Comment: What is your practical programming problem? This sounds like idle curiosity.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is. I was reading an article which stated the fs segment register points to KPCR and TEB

Answer (score 4):

The `FS` register has a segment base address associated with it either in the `LDT` or in the `GDT` (local/global segment descriptor tables). `FS` is pretty much an index into the descriptor table and it selects one of segments defined in the table.

When you access memory through `FS` (using the `FS` segment override prefix in the instruction), you access memory at a virtual address equal to the address in the instruction *plus* the segment base address.

That segment base address must coincide with the location of the thread-specific control data structures. And so, when a thread is created with its specific control data structures, the base is set to point to that data.

Those locations are different for different threads within the same process because they all share memory and shouldn't step onto each other's structures. A context switch either just updates `FS` to point to a different segment or updates the base address of the segment in the descriptor table and then reloads `FS` so the change is observed by the CPU.

When a thread transitions from user mode to kernel mode, `FS` and what it points to is untrusted from the kernel's POV, and I expect the kernel to reload `FS` with a value pointing to the kernel-side thread-specific data structures. On the way back, the user mode `FS` should be restored. In reality things may be a little more complicated, but this should give you an idea.

In 64-bit mode you even have the `SWAPGS` instruction to quickly exchange the contents of the `GS` register, playing a role similar to that of `FS` in 32-bit modes.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, so I assume these values are popped and pushed onto the threads user and kernel stacks when switching between rings. As the KPCR has maintains detail such as last, current and next thread scheduled, I would of thought this would have its own permanent segment register which wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

So the fs segment register certainly points to kpcr. Looking in windbg and after issuing the "dt nt!_kpcr", the first structure in the kpcr is NtTib or the first structure in the TEB so when people say fs points to KPCR and TEB, fs actually points to KPCR and TIB/TEB is the first data structure in KPCR.